# Change VARCHAR length of columns created dynamically in SQL table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to create columns dynamically in `table1` based on the values retrieved from the form. I am using `sqlalchemy` to do the same and using the below code:

`engine.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s;' % ('table1', col_name, "VARCHAR(100)"))`

In the above statement:

- `table1`: name of the table we are inserting the column dynamically.
- `col_name`: string containing the column name that is to be inserted.
- `VARCHAR(100)`: column type

The above code runs without any error and the new column is added. However, all the columns being created have the datatype as `VARCHAR(60)` in the table. I need to increase the length of column. Also, I'm not using `flask-sqlalchemy`.

Any ideas what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Which database engine are you using ? Can we see the code representing the table at first ?

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy library and MySQL database. I defined my engine as below:  `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:root1234@localhost/App')`

Comment: Also, my table definition only has 2 initial columns only. I have a form on submission of the form, above snippet is run along with other codes to create a new column with the details entered in the form. Therefore, I have to use execute to directly execute the query and not use the usual `session.update(record)` .